# Finding Multiple of 3 in a Array Method and returning it

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I'm currently trying to find all the multiple values of three in an array. I know hot to do it without using a method, but when I'm trying to invoke the  method and retrieve the returned array, it gives me errors and won't work.

```
public class Scratchpad extends ConsoleProgram
{
    public void run()
    {
        int[] test = {4, 7, 9, 7, 12};
        
        findMultipleOfThree testArr = new findMultipleOfThree[int[] test];
        
        System.out.println(testArr);
    }
    // Copy and paste your Unit Test method here
    
    public int findMultipleOfThree(int[] arr)
    {
        int length = arr.length;
        int[] result = new int[length];
    
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++)
        {
        
            if(arr[i] % 3 == 0)
            {
                result[i] = arr[I];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few problems in your code. I think that in your second instruction of the `run` method, you were attempting to invoke the `findMultipleOfThree` method you defined below.

To invoke a method, you simply need to type its name and pass the parameters it's expecting. In your case, the `test` array to find the elements divisible by 3. Plus, you also need to declare a second array `result` in order to store the returned array from your method with only the elements divisible by 3.

Ultimately, in your `findMultipleOfThree` method there was a small typo where you referred to the `i` variable as `I`. Java is case-sensitive, so it distinguishes between lower-case and upper-case letters.

I think this is what you were trying to write.

```
public class Scratchpad extends ConsoleProgram {
    public void run() {
        int[] test = {4, 7, 9, 7, 12};
        int[] result = findMultipleOfThree(test);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(result));
    }

    public static int[] findMultipleOfThree(int[] arr) {
        int length = arr.length;
        int[] result = new int[length];
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (arr[i] % 3 == 0) {
                result[i] = arr[i];
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're mixing up methods and classes. You can't declare an instance of a method, and they aren't types you can use for the type of a variable. If you want to call the method, you'd want to use something like `int result = findMultipleOfThree(test);` and print the result of that with `System.out.println(result);`
Hope this helps!